# performSegueWithIdentifier tricks to avoid initial delay

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

Hi there I have a ViewController performing a segue on a button.

```
- (IBAction)moveToCoolViewButtonTapped {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toCoolView" sender:nil];
}
```

This works fine, apart from an annoying delay the first time it's performed, I guess due to the view not being initialized yet. I obviously don't want to have to prematurely create a lot of views. (There are several others segues planned from the same viewController). So, a long shot perhaps: but I wondered if anyone had any brilliantly inspired tricks to avoid the initial lag?

Answer (score 2):

try replace this

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toCoolView" sender:nil];
```

with this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toCoolView" sender:nil];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
toCoolView *yourViewController = (toCoolView *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"toCoolView"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

Try that mate

Comment: Thanks, but nope. Exactly the same result, which makes sense cause it's basically doing exactly the same thing (initiating then displaying).

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same Problem. Came across your post looking for solution. I think i finally found the problem.

The problems is not your in performSegueWithIdentifier but its in your destination controller (Wherever "toCoolView" takes you). check its viewDidLoad and see if there is anything that might be taking extra time to load. In my case i was allocating and initializing UIImagepickerController which was causing the delay so I removed it from there and placed it in ViewDidAppear.

Just try commenting out every thing in your viewDidLoad of your destination controller and see if it speeds up the seque.

hope it helps